# How to auto-embed map by importing .ics file?

Tags: location, icalendar, rfc5545

I am editing `.ics` files and I would like to automatically get an embedded map on the imported events. As the name I associate to the `LOCATION` field is not often matching the generic locations (the ones listed by Apple Calendar when creating an event manually), I made some research and found out that it was possible using the `GEO` field. Unfortunately, nothing happens when I enter valid data there...

Here is my test .ics file

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:Testing
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E008000000000C39F366D366D601000000000000000
 010000000BDB756416E2A9C428ED267955FCFBC3M
SUMMARY:Test event
DTSTART:20201138T181500Z
DTEND:2020113T203000Z
CLASS:PUBLIC
DTSTAMP:20200921T104743Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
LOCATION:Home Gym
GEO:50.633981;5.586320
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: According to the vCard specification (https://geouri.org/2010/06/10/geo-and-vcards/), the format of the coordinates should be
`GEO:50.633981,5.586320` instead of `GEO:50.633981;5.586320` (coma instead of semi-colon)

Comment: But here it is a vEvent which is part of vCalendar and  [following these specifications](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.8.1.6), it is a semicolon. I still tried with a comma but nothing changes